# PostgreSQL - Joining on index from concaternated columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to join two tables together, one of them a subquery that returns a concatenated column, with PostgreSQL 9.2 but it is taking a long time.

In essence, my query is:

```
select *
from (
  select (s.a || ':' || s.b) source_key
  from source s
) sourcedata
join audit a on a.source = sourcedata.source_key
```

I have indexes on source.a, source.b and audit.source. Though it takes a long time.

I have tried adding an index on source:

```
create index source_key_idx on source((a || ':' || b));
```

This made a small difference to performance.

Is it possible to do this join explicitly on the concatenated index? Or is it already doing this?

My next choice was to add a new column or function that results in the concatenated value and index and join upon that.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest writing the query without the subquery:

```
select *
from source s join
     audit a
     on a.source = (s.a || ':' || s.b).
```

Then for this query, I would suggest an index on `audit(source)`.  This query plan should be a scan of `source` with a lookup on the index value in `audit`.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I have an index already on audit(source). 

I have tried your suggestion on removing the subquery and just directly joining on the concat'd columns, but unfortunately it made no difference to the performance.

If it helps give context, there's about 300k rows in each table.

Comment: @Steven . . . Is the index being used in the query plan?